# Tile/grid layout in jquery mobile as mobile app home screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with making my mobile app home screen look like the image below, I have tried using grids but everything aligns to the left.

Has anyone successfully used grids in jquery mobile as home screen with icons?

[image: design I want]

Comment: you should always add your attempts(html, css,javascript, jQuery) to such a question. Else we cant really say where your problems lies... Did you read the grid api from jquery mobile https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/?

Comment: that helped thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a quick example that should help you on how to create such a home screen.
The reason everything aligns to the left in your trys might be because you added 
 `style="text-align: left"` to your grids? Cant really tell without any code from your side. 
 Here is the 
 [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5vn5w9/4/)